# Python Spritz speed reader imitator: Need help from Pyglet users

Tags: python, pyglet

Link to repository of more fleshed out code: [github.com/jamesbisno/PySpeedReader](http://github.com/jamesbisno/PySpeedReader)

The problem below sloppily fixed by manually killing calculated idle time by returning self.clock.get_sleep_time(False) in the app event loop and using os.sleep to create pause and processor management.

After using this program and forcing Pyglet to ignore sleep time, I've noticed it is processor intensive. It really heats up my machine, and a fire hazard in my bed. If anyone could help me bend Pyglets clock so that I get the proper words per minutes without forcing the computer into overdrive, that would be greatly appreciated. Setting the frame rate doesn't work. The program seems to want to speed up only when events are activated, which oddly included mouse-scrolling (an invent not handled in the code).

If you plan on using the below code, please put the program in a folder alone with only one text doc (Tkinter isn't working for me). Each new text creates a unique bookmark file, which they retrieve automatically. Click the face of the window to toggle between settings and reader. Occasionally UTF encoding will crash the program, you will be bookmarked before the program shuts down. Add the UTF coding to the UTF list.

```
import pyglet
from pyglet.gl import *
import os
import pyglet.app.base


for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk('./'):
    for file in files:
        if ".txt" in file and "SaveSpot" not in file:
            filename = file
            break

f = open(filename, 'r')
w = f.read()
f.close()
UTF = ["\xef","\xbb","\xbf","\xe2","\x80","\x99","\x00","\xe2","\x80","\x9c","\x9d","\xa6","\x94","\xc3","\xa9","\x98","0x98"]

for elem in UTF:
    w = w.replace(elem,"")
words = w.split()
wordslist = []
c = 0
hyphen = False
for word in words:
    if "-" in word and hyphen == False:
        place = word.find("-")
        words.insert(c+1,word[place:])
        w = word[:place]
        hyphen = True
    else:
        w = word
        if "," in word and hyphen == False: #hyphen is now used for comma detection if revised, add comma and hypen detection at end
            hyphen = True
            words.insert(c+1, word)
        else:
            hyphen = False

    if ("." in word or "?" in word or "!" in word or ":" in word or ";" in word) and hyphen == False:
        words.insert(c+1," ")
        words.insert(c+2," ")
    wordlist = []
    wordlength = len(w)
    # these are the rules the roughly seem to mimic spritz
    if wordlength > 8:
        if w[3] == w[2]:
            wordlist = [w[0:2],w[2],w[3:]]
        else:
            wordlist = [w[0:3],w[3],w[4:]]
    elif wordlength < 9 and wordlength > 5 :
        if w[2] == w[1]:
            wordlist = [w[0:1],w[1],w[2:]]
        else:
            wordlist = [w[0:2],w[2],w[3:]]
    elif wordlength == 5:
        wordlist = [w[0],w[1],w[2:]]
    elif wordlength == 4:
        wordlist = [w[0],w[1],w[2:]]
    elif wordlength == 3:
        wordlist = [w[0],w[1],w[2]]

    elif wordlength == 2:
        wordlist = [w[0],w[1],""]
    else:
        wordlist = ["",w,""]
    wordslist.append([wordlist[0],wordlist[1],wordlist[2]])
    c += 1

#------------------------------------------------------
states = []
window = pyglet.window.Window(width=600, height=140) # width = 335 Height = 70
pyglet.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1)
batch = pyglet.graphics.Batch()
batch2 = pyglet.graphics.Batch()

class PausedState:
    def __init__(self):
        self.WPM = 500
        fontSize = int(window.width * .05)
        fontType =  'Times New Roman' # 'Ariel'
        center = int(window.width//2.9)
        self.save = pyglet.text.Label("Save", font_name=fontType,font_size=fontSize,color=(0, 0, 0, 255),x=window.width/5.2, y=window.height/2, anchor_x='right', anchor_y='center', batch = batch2)
        self.load = pyglet.text.Label("Load", font_name=fontType,font_size=fontSize,color=(0, 0, 0, 255),x=window.width/2.5, y=window.height/2, anchor_x='right', anchor_y='center', batch = batch2)
        self.back = pyglet.text.Label("<=50", font_name=fontType,font_size=fontSize,color=(0, 0, 0, 255),x=window.width/1.65, y=window.height/2, anchor_x='right', anchor_y='center', batch = batch2)
        self.WPMtag = pyglet.text.Label("wpm:", font_name=fontType,font_size=fontSize*.9,color=(0, 0, 0, 255),x=window.width/1.25, y=window.height/2.2, anchor_x='right', anchor_y='center', batch = batch2)
        self.WPMdisplay = pyglet.text.Label(str(self.WPM), font_name=fontType,font_size=fontSize*1.2,color=(0, 0, 0, 255),x=window.width/1.015, y=window.height/2.0, anchor_x='right', anchor_y='center', batch = batch2)
        self.arrowKeys = pyglet.text.Label("Use Arrow Keys", font_name=fontType,font_size=fontSize*.52,color=(0, 0, 0, 255),x=window.width/1.014, y=window.height/1.07, anchor_x='right', anchor_y='center', batch = batch2)

        dist = 0
        line1 = (int((window.width/20)+dist), int(window.height/4.5),int((window.width/4.5)+dist), int(window.height/4.5))
        line2 = (int((window.width/4.5)+dist),int(window.height-(window.height/4.5)),int((window.width/20)+dist), int(window.height-(window.height/4.5)))
        line3 = ((int(window.width/20)+dist), int(window.height-(window.height/4.5)),int((window.width/20)+dist),int(window.height/4.5))
        line4 = (int((window.width/4.5)+dist),int(window.height/4.5), int((window.width/4.5)+dist), int(window.height-(window.height/4.5)))
        dist = window.width/5
        line5 = (int((window.width/20)+dist), int(window.height/4.5),int((window.width/4.5)+dist), int(window.height/4.5))
        line6 = (int((window.width/4.5)+dist),int(window.height-(window.height/4.5)),int((window.width/20)+dist), int(window.height-(window.height/4.5)))
        line7 = (int((window.width/20)+dist), int(window.height-(window.height/4.5)),int((window.width/20)+dist),int(window.height/4.5))
        line8 = (int((window.width/4.5)+dist),int(window.height/4.5), int((window.width/4.5)+dist), int(window.height-(window.height/4.5)))
        dist = window.width/2.5
        line9 = (int((window.width/20)+dist), int(window.height/4.5),int((window.width/4.5)+dist), int(window.height/4.5))
        line10 = (int((window.width/4.5)+dist),int(window.height-(window.height/4.5)),int((window.width/20)+dist), int(window.height-(window.height/4.5)))
        line11 = (int((window.width/20)+dist), int(window.height-(window.height/4.5)),int((window.width/20)+dist),int(window.height/4.5))
        line12 = (int((window.width/4.5)+dist),int(window.height/4.5), int((window.width/4.5)+dist), int(window.height-(window.height/4.5)))
        dist = window.width / 1.3
        line13 = (int((window.width/20)+dist), int(window.height/4.5),int((window.width/4.5)+dist), int(window.height/4.5))
        line14 = (int((window.width/4.5)+dist),int(window.height-(window.height/4.5)),int((window.width/20)+dist), int(window.height-(window.height/4.5)))
        line15 = (int((window.width/20)+dist), int(window.height-(window.height/4.5)),int((window.width/20)+dist),int(window.height/4.5))
        line16 = (int((window.width/4.5)+dist),int(window.height/4.5), int((window.width/4.5)+dist), int(window.height-(window.height/4.5)))



        batch2.add(2, GL_LINES, None, ('v2i', line1))
        batch2.add(2, GL_LINES, None, ('v2i', line2))
        batch2.add(2, GL_LINES, None, ('v2i', line3))
        batch2.add(2, GL_LINES, None, ('v2i', line4))
        batch2.add(2, GL_LINES, None, ('v2i', line5))
        batch2.add(2, GL_LINES, None, ('v2i', line6))
        batch2.add(2, GL_LINES, None, ('v2i', line7))
        batch2.add(2, GL_LINES, None, ('v2i', line8))
        batch2.add(2, GL_LINES, None, ('v2i', line9))
        batch2.add(2, GL_LINES, None, ('v2i', line10))
        batch2.add(2, GL_LINES, None, ('v2i', line11))
        batch2.add(2, GL_LINES, None, ('v2i', line12))
        batch2.add(2, GL_LINES, None, ('v2i', line13))
        batch2.add(2, GL_LINES, None, ('v2i', line14))
        batch2.add(2, GL_LINES, None, ('v2i', line15))
        batch2.add(2, GL_LINES, None, ('v2i', line16))

    def update(self, dt):
        pass

    def WPMprovider(self, alteration = 0):
        self.WPM += alteration
        return 60.00/self.WPM

class ReadState:
    def __init__(self,wordslist):
        center = int(window.width//2.9)
        lineGap = window.height/8
        pointLineL = int(lineGap * .9)
        fontSize = int(window.height * .37)
        fontType =  'Times New Roman' # 'Ariel'
        self.wordslist = wordslist
        self.count = 0


        self.label = pyglet.text.Label("", font_name=fontType,font_size=fontSize,color=(0, 0, 0, 255), x=center - int(fontSize/2.5), y=(window.height//2) + 5, anchor_x='right', anchor_y='center',batch = batch)
        self.label2 = pyglet.text.Label("", font_name=fontType, font_size=fontSize,color=(250, 65, 65,255), x=center, y=(window.height//2) + 5, anchor_x='center', anchor_y='center',batch = batch)
        self.label3 = pyglet.text.Label("", font_name=fontType,font_size=fontSize,color=(0, 0, 0, 255), x= center + int(fontSize/2.5), y=(window.height//2) + 5, anchor_x='left', anchor_y='center',batch = batch)
        pyglet.gl.glLineWidth(2)
        pyglet.gl.glColor3f(0,0,0)
        batch.add(8, GL_LINES, None, ('v2i', (lineGap, window.height - lineGap, window.width-lineGap, window.height - lineGap, lineGap, lineGap, window.width-lineGap,lineGap, center, lineGap, center, lineGap + pointLineL, center, window.height-lineGap, center, window.height - lineGap - pointLineL)))
    def update(self,dt):
        self.label.text = self.wordslist[self.count][0]
        self.label2.text = self.wordslist[self.count][1]
        self.label3.text = self.wordslist[self.count][2]
        self.count +=1
    def savePlace(self):
        return self.count-1
    def loadPlace(self,count):
        if count == -50:
            self.count -= 50
        else:
            self.count = count



@window.event                        
def on_draw():
    if states[1] == ps:
        window.clear()
        batch2.draw()
    else:
        window.clear()
        batch.draw()

@window.event 
def on_mouse_press(x, y, button, modifiers):
    if button != 1:
        pyglet.EventLoop.exit()
    if states[1] == ps:
        if (window.width/20 < x < window.width/4.5) and window.height/4.5 < y < window.height-(window.height/4.5):
            location = rs.savePlace()
            f = open("SaveSpot" + filename,"w")
            f.write(str(location))
            f.close()
        elif (((window.width/20) + (window.width/5)) < x < ((window.width/5)+(window.width/4.5))) and window.height/4.5 < y < window.height-(window.height/4.5):
            f = open("SaveSpot" + filename,"r")
            place = f.read()
            f.close()
            rs.loadPlace(int(place))
        elif ((window.width/20) + (window.width/2.5) < x < (window.width/2.5)+(window.width/4.5)) and window.height/4.5 < y < window.height-(window.height/4.5):
            rs.loadPlace(-50)
        else:
            states.reverse()
    else:
        states.reverse()



@window.event 
def on_key_press(symbol, modifiers):
    ps.arrowKeys.delete()
    if symbol == 65362 or symbol == 65363: #up and right arrow keys
        ps.WPMprovider(50)
        wpm = int(60/ps.WPMprovider())
        ps.WPMdisplay.text = (str(wpm))
        changeClock()
    if symbol == 65364 or symbol == 65361: #down and left arrow keys
        wpm = int(60/ps.WPMprovider())
        if  wpm > 50:
            ps.WPMprovider(-50)
            wpm = int(60/ps.WPMprovider())
            ps.WPMdisplay.text = (str(wpm))
            changeClock()
        else:
            pass


def update(dt):
    states[-1].update(dt)

rs = ReadState(wordslist)
ps = PausedState()
states.append(rs)
states.append(ps)


def changeClock():
    pyglet.clock.unschedule(update)
    WPM = ps.WPMprovider()
    pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(update, WPM)

pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(update, 60.0/500)
pyglet.clock.set_fps_limit(20)

class MyEventLoop(pyglet.app.base.EventLoop):

    def idle(self):
        dt = self.clock.update_time()
        redraw_all = self.clock.call_scheduled_functions(dt)

        for window in pyglet.app.windows:
            if redraw_all or (window._legacy_invalid and window.invalid):
                window.switch_to()
                window.dispatch_event('on_draw')
                window.flip()
                window._legacy_invalid = False

        return self.clock.get_sleep_time(False)


    def exit(self):
        pyglet.app.base.EventLoop.exit(self)


def run():
    pyglet.app.event_loop = MyEventLoop()
    try:
        pyglet.app.run()
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        print UnicodeDecodeError
        location = rs.savePlace()
        f = open("SaveSpot" + filename,"w")
        f.write(str(location))
        f.close()

run()
```

Below are 500 words from the beginning of Native Son for use with the program.

> The sound of the alarm that opens Native Son was Richard Wright’s urgent call in 1940 to
>   America to awaken from its self-induced slumber about the reality of race relations in the
>   nation. As proud, rich, and powerful as America was, Wright insisted, the nation was facing a
>   grave danger, one that would ultimately destroy the United States if its dimensions and devious
>   complexity were not recognized. Native Son was intended to be America’s guide in
>   confronting this danger.
>
> Wright believed that few Americans, black or white, were prepared to face squarely and
>   honestly the most profound consequences of more than two centuries of the enslavement and
>   segregation of blacks in North America. The dehumanization of African Americans during
>   slavery had been followed in the long aftermath of the Civil War by their often brutal
>   repression in the South and by conditions of life in many respects equally severe in the
>   nominally integrated North. Nevertheless, Wright knew, blacks and whites alike continued to
>   cling to a range of fantasies about the true nature of the relationship between the races even
>   as the nation lurched inexorably toward a possible collapse over the fundamental question of
>   justice for the despised African American minority.
>
> Among blacks, the centuries of abuse and exploitation had created ways of life marked by
>   patterns of duplicity, including self-deception, as well as something far more forbidding and
>   lethal. Slavery and neo-slavery had led not simply to the development of a psychology of
>   timidity, passivity, and even cowardice among the African American masses, Wright suggests in
>   Native Son, but also to an ominous emerging element of which Bigger Thomas, the central
>   character of the novel, is a reliable if particularly forbidding example. Although this new
>   element was itself susceptible to fantasy and self-deception, what set its members apart from
>   other blacks was the depth of their estrangement from both black and white culture, their
>   hatred of both groups, and their sometimes unconscious but powerful identification of violence
>   against other human beings as the most appropriate response to the disastrous conditions of
>   their lives. Within the confines of the black world, this violence was easily directed at fellow
>   blacks; but increasingly, Wright warned his readers, this violence would be aimed at whites.
>
> Wright understood fully that this message was radical to the core, and that his novel Native
>   Son was like no other book in the history of African American literature. In 1937, in his
>   landmark essay “Blueprint for Negro Writing,” he had characterized African American literature
>   to that time as fundamentally lacking in forthrightness and independence. “Generally
>   speaking,” he had written reprovingly, “Negro writing in the past has been confined to humble
>   novels, poems, and plays, prim and decorous ambassadors who went a-begging to white
>   America…dressed in the knee-pants of servility…. For the most part these artistic ambassadors
>   were received as though they were French poodles who do clever tricks.” To some extent,
>   Wright certainly had overstated the case for the inadequacy of past black writers. At least since

Comment: +1 for Native Son--fantastic book.

Comment: have you yet made a public repository for this code?

Comment: No, please read the above comments. Program is a potential fire hazard in bed.

Comment: @JamesBeezho Don't be so dramatic. Your PC would shut down if that were actually an issue. If it's worth sharing publicly here, it's worth putting somewhere like Github.

Comment: https://github.com/jamesbisno/PySpeedReader

Comment: I'm voting to close this post as off-topic because, after a number of edits, there isn't really a question.